# What are the differences between the RPG-7 and M2-CG, other than appearance?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Both the RPG-7 and the M2-CG are anti-vehicle weapons for the Engineer, but as far as I can tell they act about the same.

Are there any differences between the two, and why would you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CG has significantly larger blast radius and faster projectile speed, but it has lower total damage. It's much better against infantry, good against helicopters, but weaker against tanks and light armour.